# Remove OR Replace "mailed by" field with DKIM & SPF enabled in AWS SES

Tags: email, postfix, spf, dkim, amazon-ses

Is it possible to **remove** the `mailed by: us-west-2.amazonses.com` field in an email **or replace** it with `mailed by: example.com`? Amazon forums, this site, and google searches are very unclear. I am using Amazon SES to send the email. The `via` portion of the email is already removed, as I have a TXT record and DKIM enabled on the domain to prove ownership.

I understand that Amazon SES is the endpoint and is sending this email, but I'd like to know how to not advertise the fact.

I've also enabled SPF records on my domain, which I believe is just accomplishing the same feat twice if I'm using DKIM (I need verification if this is correct), but it still is labeling itself as mailed by `amazonses.com`. I've asked this question on Amazon SES Developer Forums and all google searches within the last year come back to this question or sites that have copied it. Is there a better place to ask this question?

Comment: SPF and DKIM should be sufficient. Do your headers show that they're passing those checks?

Comment: Running `dig _amazonses.mydomain.com txt` shows the record Amazon told to put in, and the three CNAME values are also on the domain, as well.

Comment: SPF validators show that the record is formatted correctly and valid, and Amazon is showing that DKIM is enabled and verified.

Comment: did you find a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You can replace `mailed-by: us-west-2.amazonses.com` with `mailed by: sub.example.com` but not with `mailed-by: example.com`.

In other words, unnaked domain (with subdomain) like `sub.example.com` is possible but naked domain like `example.com` is impossible to replace with `us-west-2.amazonses.com` for `mailed-by`.

To replace `us-west-2.amazonses.com` with `sub.example.com` for `mailed-by`, you must create a `custom MAIL FROM domain`.

The below is how you create the custom MAIL FROM domain `sub.example.com`.

Click on the domain `example.com`.

[image]

---

Then, the detail is shown.

[image]

---

Then, click on `MAIL FROM Domain` to show `Set MAIL FROM Domain` button.

[image]

---

Then, clicking on `Set MAIL FROM Domain` button, the window is open.

[image]

---

Then, put the subdomain "sub" to the field and click on `Set MAIL FROM Domain` button.

[image]

---

Then, the `MX Record` and `SPF Record` are shown. You must add the `MX Record` and `SPF Record` to `Route 53` in addition to the records of the domain `example.com` to verify the custom MAIL FROM domain `sub.example.com`.

[image]

---

Finally, check if the custom MAIL FROM domain `sub.example.com` is verified under `MAIL FROM domain` section.

[image]

---

If `MAIL FROM domain status` is still `pending verification`, click on `retry` in blue.

[image]

---

Then, it will be verified.

[image]

---

After the custom MAIL FROM domain is verified, `mailed-by` is  `sub.example.com` whether or not you send emails using `example.com` or `sub.example.com` and whether or not your account is in the sandbox.

Answer (score 2):

The mailed-by header is the usually used to persist the content of the envelope from or MAIL FROM through forwarding. Amazon do not allow the MAIL FROM to be customised. The following quote is from an Amazon employee in a comment on an [blog post about SPF & DKIM](http://sesblog.amazon.com/post/Tx3IREZBQXXL8O8/SPF-and-Amazon-SES):

> The headers you mentioned [mailed-by] seem to be something appended by an ISP after the message left Amazon SES, rather than standard message headers. We unfortunately do not have control over receiver add-ons.
>
> Nevertheless, assuming that the “mailed-by” value is based on the MAIL-FROM, the answer would be that right now all emails sent through Amazon SES have amazonses.com (or a subdomain of that) as the MAIL-FROM domain. We don't currently support its customization
>
> Posted by  Adrian@AWS  on  November 4, 2014 8:31:29 AM PST